# Build a variable made with 2 sub-stings of another variable in bash

Tags: bash, sed

Here is a script I use:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d -name "single_copy_busco_sequences"); do  
    sppname=$(dirname $(dirname $(dirname $dir))| sed 's@./@@g');
    for file in ${dir}/*.faa; do name=$(basename $file); cp $file /Users/admin/Documents/busco_aa/${sppname}_${name}; sed -i '' 's@>@>'${sppname}'|@g' /Users/admin/Documents/busco_aa/${sppname}_${name}; cut -f 1 -d ":" /Users/admin/Documents/busco_aa/${sppname}_${name} > /Users/admin/Documents/busco_aa/${sppname}_${name}.1;
    done;
done
```

The sppname variable is something like Gender_species
do you know how could I add a line in my script to creat a new variable called abbrev which transformes Gender_species into Genspe, `the 3 first letters` cat with the `3 first` letters after `_`

exemples:

```
Homo_sapiens gives Homsap
Canis_lupus gives Canlup
```

etc

Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all with bash built-in *parameter expansions*. Specifically, *string indexes* and *substring removal*.

```
$ a=Homo_sapiens; prefix=${a:0:3}; a=${a#*_}; postfix=${a:0:3}; echo $prefix$postfix
Homsap

$ a=Canis_lupus; prefix=${a:0:3}; a=${a#*_}; postfix=${a:0:3}; echo $prefix$postfix
Canlup
```

Using bash built-ins is always more efficient than spawning separate subshell(s) to invoke utilities to accomplish the same thing.

**Explanation**

Your *string index* form (bash only) allows you to index characters from within a string, e.g.

```
* ${parameter:offset:length}  ## indexes are zero based, ${a:0:2} is 1st 2 chars
```

Where `parameter` is simply the variable name holding the string.

(you can index from the end of a string by using a negative offset preceded by a `space` or enclosed in parenthesis, e.g. `a=12345; echo ${a: -3:2}` outputs `"34"`)

```
    prefix=${a:0:3}   ## save the first 3 characters in prefix
    a=${a#*_}         ## remove the front of the string through '_' (see below)
    postfix=${a:0:3}  ## save the first 3 characters after '_'
```

Your *substring removal* forms (POSIX) are:

- `${parameter#word}` trim to 1st occurrence of word from parameter from left
- `${parameter##word}` trim to last occurrence of word from parameter from left

and

- `${parameter%word}` trim to 1st occurrence of word from parameter from right
- `${parameter%%word}` trim to last occurrence of word from parameter from right

(*word* can contain globbing to expand to a pattern as well)

```
   a=${a#*_}   ## trim from left up to (and including) the first '_'
```

See [bash(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for full details.

Comment: Whoua, thank your for all these very clear informations it was kind of you to take the time!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Bash provides a full set of simply amazing parameter expansions that can do just about anything that needs to be done to a sting. It just takes making friends with them. The entire section under "Parameter Expansion" in the man-page does a good job explaining them all (though your will probably only use a handful on a regular basis, it's good to know where to look when you find yourself stuck). Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a regular expression with sed:

```
echo "Homo_sapiens" | sed -e s'/^\(...\).*_\(...\).*/\1\2/'
Homsap
```

start, get 3 chars (to keep in \1), anything, _, anything, get 3 chars (to keep in \2), anything

Replace echo "Homo_sapiens" by your $dir thing

PS: will fail if you have less than 3 chars in one word